# MySQL: Still can't LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'

Tags: php, mysql

Using Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64 / PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) w/ FPM / MySQL InnoDB version 5.5.35

I've created a PHP script that downloads a text file from a remote server and then attempts to import it with the ***LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'.***

I've gone through the process of modifying the php.ini file:

```
[MySQL]
; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysql.allow_local_infile
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
```

I've modified my.cnf (both [mysql] and [mysqld] entries):

```
local-infile=1
local-infile
```

I've run MySQL from the terminal and then issue:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
```

I've manually started and stopped MySQL with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --enable-local-infile
```

After each of these commands I can run ***SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';*** and it always says the value is ON. I have no problem whatsoever executing my ***LOAD DATA*** command from MySQL prompt but if I try to run the ***LOAD DATA*** stored in a PHP file it errors out with:

***The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version***

From what I've read, there seems to be a few who suggest to recompile PHP with "--with-mysql=/usr" but that seems like a real sledge hammer approach to me, maybe I'm wrong. I can issue ANY MySQL query except for that that from a PHP file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE does not work from php 5.5 using PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226631/load-data-local-infile-does-not-work-from-php-5-5-using-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write twice the following line into the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

then under paragraph [mysql]
and paragraph [mysqld]

add the following line :

```
local-infile=1
```

then save the file

then restart